# Compiling a windows service with an output type of Exe

Tags: c#, windows-services

Currently when developing a windows service I modify the csproj to set the OutputType to Exe in debug mode so that I get a console window and I can easily debug the service.

What I'm curious about is, is there any issue with putting it into production like this in release mode?  I don't see the console window, it seems to be not shown or hidden or not created when the service is installed via InstallUtil and then started.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Trace output would be just as easy for debugging purposes, and would not require the service to create a console window. You could even leave it in in release builds.

Comment: I do use Trace output, as well as a lot of other configurable logging options.  The point was simply if there was a negative impact to building it as a console app when deploying in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most services are usually exe output types. And yes, there will be no console when it is running as a service but as long as you are not reading from the console for anything it should not be a problem. You can write to the console as a service and the text will just be ignored by the system.

Usually what I do is I make the program watch for the string `--debug` to be passed in as a command line parameter, if it is it starts up the serivce as a console app and if not it starts it up as a service. Here is a example of how to do it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        var debugMode = args.Contains("--debug", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

        if (!debugMode)
        {
            ServiceBase[] servicesToRun =
            {
                new MyService();
            };
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
        }
        else
        {
            var service = new MyService();
            service.StartService(args);
            Console.WriteLine("Service is now running, press enter to stop...");
            Console.ReadLine();
            service.StopService();
        }
    }
}
```

Then inside the service code I do

```
public partial class MyService : ServiceBase
{
    internal void StartService(string[] args)
    {
        OnStart(args);
    }

    internal void StopService()
    {
        OnStop();
    }

    //... The rest of the code here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  You nailed it on the top portion, and the bottom half I think will help other developers.  I do something similar but we don't use command line arguments.    Here's a gist showing how we start our stuff up with dependency injection and the conditional attribute.

https://gist.github.com/jsheldon/95ee922088abf28eb6ec04dcdd1e1fb2